# Arquillian missing dependency running tests

Tags: maven, junit, integration-testing, wildfly, jboss-arquillian

This question has been asked many times but noone of the answers (that I found) seems to help.

So, I have a wildfly-server running locally and then run a maven-command. From the server logs it seems to deploy the war-files and it doesn't complain at all. In maven it seems to run the tests but all tests returns:

```
<<< ERROR! java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.junit.runner.Runner
```

So, I look in the deployed war-file and there I find junit- and arquillian-files that contains org/junit/runner/Runner.class. So, that shouldn't cause the problem.

Next I run mvn dependency:tree to verify that the maven-command and the junit and arquallian dependencies are there too. I mess around with  for those dependencies but doesn't get any changes.

The only way, that I found, to change the error has been to change the junit-version from 4.12 to 4.8 but I don't know if it is a step forward when it compains about another class (org.junit.rules.RunRules).

Relevant dependencies in pom-file:

```xml
      <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>arquillian-junit-core</artifactId>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
          <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-remote</artifactId>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
          <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-depchain</artifactId>
          <type>pom</type>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
          <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven</artifactId>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Dump of the relevant files deployed to wildfly:

```html
/WEB-INF/lib/querydsl-jpa-4.1.4.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/querydsl-core-4.1.4.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/guava-21.0.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/jsr305-3.0.1.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/mysema-commons-lang-0.2.4.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/bridge-method-annotation-1.14.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.24.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/querydsl-sql-4.1.4.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/joda-time-2.9.7.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.javax-inject-1_2.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.8.1.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-core-2.8.1.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/disruptor-3.3.6.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/commons-collections4-4.1.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/logging-util-3.0.0.11-SNAPSHOT.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/arquillian-junit-container-1.1.13.Final.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/arquillian-junit-core-1.1.13.Final.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/arquillian-test-api-1.1.13.Final.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/arquillian-core-api-1.1.13.Final.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/arquillian-test-spi-1.1.13.Final.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/arquillian-core-spi-1.1.13.Final.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/arquillian-container-test-api-1.1.13.Final.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/shrinkwrap-api-1.2.6.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/arquillian-container-test-spi-1.1.13.Final.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/arquillian-container-spi-1.1.13.Final.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-base-2.0.0-alpha-10.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/arquillian-core-impl-base-1.1.13.Final.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/arquillian-test-impl-base-1.1.13.Final.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/arquillian-container-impl-base-1.1.13.Final.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/arquillian-config-api-1.1.13.Final.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/arquillian-config-impl-base-1.1.13.Final.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/shrinkwrap-descriptors-spi-2.0.0-alpha-10.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/arquillian-container-test-impl-base-1.1.13.Final.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/shrinkwrap-impl-base-1.2.6.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/shrinkwrap-spi-1.2.6.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/junit-4.12.jar
```

Part of the mvn dependency:tree output

```html
[INFO] +- org.jmockit:jmockit:jar:1.22:test
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- com.h2database:h2:jar:1.4.193:test
[INFO] +- com.openpojo:openpojo:jar:0.8.4:test
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.1.3.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:provided
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.3:provided
[INFO] +- com.sun.el:el-ri:jar:1.0:test
[INFO] +- org.jboss.arquillian.junit:arquillian-junit-core:jar:1.1.13.Final:test
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.arquillian.test:arquillian-test-spi:jar:1.1.13.Final:test
[INFO] |     \- org.jboss.arquillian.core:arquillian-core-spi:jar:1.1.13.Final:test
[INFO] +- org.jboss.arquillian.junit:arquillian-junit-container:jar:1.1.13.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.test:arquillian-test-api:jar:1.1.13.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-test-api:jar:1.1.13.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-api:jar:1.2.6:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-test-spi:jar:1.1.13.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-spi:jar:1.1.13.Final:test
[INFO] |  |     \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors:shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-base:jar:2.0.0-alpha-10:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.core:arquillian-core-impl-base:jar:1.1.13.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.test:arquillian-test-impl-base:jar:1.1.13.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-impl-base:jar:1.1.13.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.config:arquillian-config-api:jar:1.1.13.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.config:arquillian-config-impl-base:jar:1.1.13.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors:shrinkwrap-descriptors-spi:jar:2.0.0-alpha-10:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-test-impl-base:jar:1.1.13.Final:test
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-impl-base:jar:1.2.6:test
[INFO] |     \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-spi:jar:1.2.6:test
[INFO] +- org.wildfly:wildfly-arquillian-container-remote:jar:8.2.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.wildfly:wildfly-arquillian-common:jar:8.2.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.testenricher:arquillian-testenricher-cdi:jar:1.1.13.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.testenricher:arquillian-testenricher-ejb:jar:1.1.13.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.testenricher:arquillian-testenricher-initialcontext:jar:1.1.13.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.testenricher:arquillian-testenricher-osgi:jar:2.1.0.CR2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.testenricher:arquillian-testenricher-resource:jar:1.1.13.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.protocol:arquillian-protocol-servlet:jar:1.1.13.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.wildfly:wildfly-arquillian-testenricher-msc:jar:8.2.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.wildfly:wildfly-server:jar:8.2.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.wildfly:wildfly-controller:jar:8.2.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- org.wildfly:wildfly-core-security:jar:8.2.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  |  \- org.wildfly:wildfly-core-security-api:jar:8.2.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- org.jboss:staxmapper:jar:1.1.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.wildfly:wildfly-domain-http-interface:jar:8.2.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- org.wildfly:wildfly-domain-management:jar:8.2.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.wildfly:wildfly-deployment-repository:jar:8.2.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.wildfly:wildfly-patching:jar:8.2.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- org.wildfly:wildfly-cli:jar:8.2.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |     +- org.jboss.aesh:aesh:jar:0.33.11:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |     |  \- org.fusesource.jansi:jansi:jar:1.9:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |     \- sun.jdk:jconsole:jar:jdk:system
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.wildfly:wildfly-platform-mbean:jar:8.2.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.wildfly:wildfly-process-controller:jar:8.2.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.wildfly:wildfly-remoting:jar:8.2.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- org.wildfly:wildfly-io:jar:8.2.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.wildfly:wildfly-network:jar:8.2.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.wildfly:wildfly-version:jar:8.2.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:1.2.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.jboss.invocation:jboss-invocation:jar:1.2.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.jboss.logmanager:jboss-logmanager:jar:1.5.2.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.jboss.modules:jboss-modules:jar:1.3.3.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.jboss.stdio:jboss-stdio:jar:1.0.2.GA:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.jboss:jboss-vfs:jar:3.2.5.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- io.undertow:undertow-core:jar:1.1.8.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.jboss.msc:jboss-msc:jar:1.2.2.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.wildfly:wildfly-controller-client:jar:8.2.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.wildfly:wildfly-protocol:jar:8.2.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.jboss:jboss-dmr:jar:1.2.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.jboss.threads:jboss-threads:jar:2.1.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.wildfly:wildfly-jmx:jar:8.2.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.jboss:jboss-common-core:jar:2.2.22.GA:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.remotingjmx:remoting-jmx:jar:2.0.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.jboss.remoting:jboss-remoting:jar:4.0.0.Beta3:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.jboss.xnio:xnio-api:jar:3.2.0.Beta4:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.jboss.xnio:xnio-nio:jar:3.2.0.Beta4:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.sasl:jboss-sasl:jar:1.0.4.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.osgi:org.osgi.core:jar:5.0.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.wildfly:wildfly-arquillian-protocol-jmx:jar:8.2.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.wildfly.security:wildfly-security-manager:jar:1.0.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.protocol:arquillian-protocol-jmx:jar:1.1.13.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.osgi.metadata:jbosgi-metadata:jar:3.0.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.marshalling:jboss-marshalling-river:jar:1.4.9.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.marshalling:jboss-marshalling:jar:1.4.9.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.core:arquillian-core-api:jar:1.1.13.Final:test
[INFO] |  \- org.wildfly:wildfly-build-config:jar:8.2.1.Final:test
[INFO] +- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-depchain:pom:2.2.4:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-api:jar:2.2.4:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-spi:jar:2.2.4:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-api-maven:jar:2.2.4:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-spi-maven:jar:2.2.4:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-api-maven-archive:jar:2.2.4:test
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven-archive:jar:2.2.4:test
[INFO] |     +- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-spi-maven-archive:jar:2.2.4:test
[INFO] |     +- org.eclipse.sisu:org.eclipse.sisu.plexus:jar:0.3.0.M1:test
[INFO] |     |  +- javax.enterprise:cdi-api:jar:1.0:test
[INFO] |     |  |  \- javax.annotation:jsr250-api:jar:1.0:test
[INFO] |     |  \- org.eclipse.sisu:org.eclipse.sisu.inject:jar:0.3.0.M1:test
[INFO] |     \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-javac:jar:2.3:test
[INFO] |        \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-api:jar:2.3:test
[INFO] +- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven:jar:2.2.4:test
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.aether:aether-api:jar:1.0.0.v20140518:test
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.aether:aether-impl:jar:1.0.0.v20140518:test
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.aether:aether-spi:jar:1.0.0.v20140518:test
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.aether:aether-util:jar:1.0.0.v20140518:test
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.aether:aether-connector-basic:jar:1.0.0.v20140518:test
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.aether:aether-transport-wagon:jar:1.0.0.v20140518:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-aether-provider:jar:3.2.5:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:3.2.5:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-model-builder:jar:3.2.5:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.5.5:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:3.2.5:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:3.2.5:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-settings-builder:jar:3.2.5:test
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.21:test
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.20:test
[INFO] |  +- org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.4:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:jar:2.6:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-file:jar:2.6:test
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-http-lightweight:jar:2.6:test
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-http-shared:jar:2.6:test
[INFO] |        +- org.jsoup:jsoup:jar:1.7.2:test
[INFO] |        \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.5:provided
```

Comment: Try marking the junit dependency in your pom with `<scope>test</scope>`.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins It doesn't seem to make any difference... The error prevails...

Comment: I'm really not sure what it could be. FWIW in WildFly the test suite uses Arquillian with 4.12 and there aren't any issues.

Comment: Try with JUnit 4.12, they have changed internals since 4.8 and this might be an issue

Comment: @bartosz.majsak post as answer, works for me!